# Python GDAL import error in pycharm but work in anaconda python/console

Tags: python, import, pycharm, anaconda, gdal

A problem occurred in Pycharm, when each time I import GDAL package.

The VirEnv come from Anaconda. The only package who refuse to work is Gdal.

Gdal version 2.2.2
Python version 3.6.4
Windows  10 pro
64-bits

[image: Pycharm not work! Anaconda work!]

In pycharm :

This

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s with %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform, sys.path))
```

will return :

> Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 with [
>   'D:/.../.../.../projectFolder', 
>   'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev', 
>   'D:\...\...\...\projectFolder', 
>   'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev', 
>   'C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\python36.zip', 
>   'C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\lib', 
>   'C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName', 
>   'C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\lib\site-packages', 
>   'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend', 
>   'D:\...\...\...\projectFolder', 
>   'D:/.../.../.../projectFolder'
>   ]

At run/debug configuration in Pycharm, I add as environment Variables:
Name : PATH
Values : C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\share\gdal;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\lib;C:\Anaconda3\envs\envName\Library\mkspecs

Name: GDAL_DATA
Value : C:\Anaconda3\envs\GeoRefSoft\Library\share\gdal

I did the same with windows env. variable.

What I missed?

**UPDATE :**

I try Both terminal from Pycharm and anaconda has the exact same sys.path, but Pycharm console your work, just like a .py run, python console, etc.

What I missed?